# Getting Images With PHP And Display In Script

Tags: php

I have a blog and I want to be able to show images that are stored in a folder using a simple PHP script.  Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$folder = "$segment_url/files/photos/$post_year/$post_id/";
$filetype = ".jpg";
$files = glob($folder.$filetype, GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo "

        <img class=\"galleryPhoto\" src=\"$file\" /> // PROBLEM 1

    ";
}
?>
<?php echo $folder; ?>
<?php
$display_content = "

    <div class=\"pageSection text\">
        $content_intro
    </div>
    <div class=\"contentSpace\"></div>
    <div class=\"pageSection text\">
        // PROBLEM 2
    </div>
    <div class=\"contentSpace\"></div>
    <div class=\"pageSection text\">
        $content_conclusion
    </div>

";
?>
```

In reference to the above code:

Problem 1: Even though the path to the images folder is correct, no images are being displayed.

Problem 2: How do I get the `echoed` content to be displayed here rather than at the top of the page?

Comment: Instead of echoing the images, store them in a array / variable and echo / print the variable at the location you want them to appear? As for the images not showing, Have you checked the path in the console? are they throwing a 404 there?

Answer (score 0):

For Problem 1 : You are missing to use full image path, otherwise search will search in current directory. Try like this.

```
<img class=\"galleryPhoto\" src=\"$folder/$file\" /> // PROBLEM 1
```

Comment: What exactly you are getting after `echo $folder/$file;exit;` ? in loop?

Comment: What if you put any static path with full image url ?

Comment: It's OK now, I've used a different script and the images show up perfectly.

Comment: Can you also share that script to us?